# How to un-focus() with andt form

Tags: forms, focus, antd

I have an antd form with multiple items and I do not know where the focus is currently. I want to remove the focus from any item in an antd form automatically via code (rather than a user clicking outside of the form. You can set the focus with:

```
this.formItem.focus()
```

But I want to remove the focus. So I want something like:

```
form.unFocus()
```

Is there a method I can use to do this?

Comment: let's say you are typing into an Input if you clear the focus in code, then you can not type anymore and you have to click on the Input again. if you want to remove focus then you can use `blur()`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the `focus`, you can use `blur`.
I have used [antd Form](https://ant.design/components/form/), and I can remove the `focus` by using `ref` like so :

`myRef.current.blur();`

[image: Edit so-60760094-blur-form]